# Django-jet admin- add button for each row

Tags: django, django-admin, django-jet

I want to create a button that deletes the selected row in the table (1 button per row)

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
from import_export.admin import ImportExportMixin
from .models import Applicant


class ApplicantAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin, admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('Name', 'DOB', 'PhoneNumber', 'Address', 'Batch',
                   'created_at', 'updated_at',)
    list_filter = ('Name', 'Address', 'Batch', 'created_at', 'updated_at',)
    list_per_page = 10
    # actions = [transferdata, ]


# Register the admin class with the associated model
admin.site.register(Applicant, ApplicantAdmin)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Applicant(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=10).primary_key
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    DOB = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    PhoneNumber = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Batch = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name
```

I already know **django-jet** that provides this facility a drop-down menu, but for the whole table (i.e. not for the each row)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem by creating a function inside the required admin class.

**admin.py**

```
import django.contrib import admin
import import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
import import_export.admin import ImportExportMixin
import .models import Applicant

class ApplicantAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('Name', 'DOB', 'PhoneNumber', 'Address', 'Batch',
               'created_at', 'updated_at',)
    list_filter = ('Name', 'Address', 'Batch', 'created_at', 'updated_at',)
    list_per_page = 10
    # actions = [transferdata, ]

    @staticmethod
    def action_button(self):
        # assuming the url is saved as 'button_url'
        # enter the url to be parsed when the button will be clicked and name the button
        return format_html('<a class="button" href="%s">(name of the button)</a>' % button_url)

# Register the admin class with the associated model
admin.site.register(Applicant, AdminApplicant)
```

Create a function of the button in the **views.py**

In the **urls.py** enter the url (almost the same as in admin class) in urlpatterns of the app and call the function present in **views.py**